# Is hash based ordering possible in akka-stream-kafka?

Tags: akka-stream

I am exploring **`akka-stream-kafka`** for one of my use case and going through this [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/0.13/producer.html). According to the documentation, the producer sink divides the payload i.e. data records into all the Kafka partitions equally, which is logical. However I wanted to have control over the partition where a message is going. My use case is, I will get millions of rows with key as `record_id`, now I want to send all the records for the same `record_id` lets assume `1234` to same partition lets assume partition number `10`. So to summarized it lets say I have 1000 records and 10 partitions. Out of those 1000 records 3700 are with `record_id` `1234`. Lets say kafka sent that `record_id` to partition number 1. So I want all those 3700 records to go through partition 1 as I want to maintain the order of those records. Similarly for other `record_id`. The `plainsink` implementation that the documentation have divides the records evenly to all partition.

Is there a way I can control the record flow based on hashing of keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the `ProducerRecord`, you have the chance to provide a partition index where you want it to end up.

To calculate the partition index you can simply use `recordId % numberOfPartitions`, and you will make sure all messages with the same `recordId` will end up in the same partition.

Example below:

```
  val source: Source[Record, NotUsed] = ???

  source
    .map { record =>
      val partition = record.recordId % 10
      new ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], Record]("topic1", partition, null, record)
    }
    .runWith(Producer.plainSink(producerSettings))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, what does that `elem.recordId` represents in your answer? I cannot find its reference.

Comment: typo: elem -> record

Comment: The `partition` represents partition id here, right? When I ran my code with `partition` value 10 I saw all the records went through 10. In that case I will have to have a hashing algorithm to hash my keys in to number of partitions.

Comment: Yes, plain modulo (`%`) assumes that your record Ids are uniformly distributed, which might not always be the case. in the more general case you'll have something like `hash(record.recordId) % 10`

Comment: This `hash(record.recordId) % 10` implementation too assumes the `recordId` is numeric. I have cases where my `Id` is alphanumeric. I will have to think about those cases. Thanks for your time :)